# Vim's pop-up menu autocompletion not working correctly

Tags: vim, terminal, configuration, autocomplete, neovim

I'm using **deoplete** plugin for **autocompletion** and it works as expected but with a small trivial problem.

Using tab key to select completion goes to the last item instead of first and vice versa for shift-tab which got fixed by following 2 lines but whenever I open a file in new vim instance the following lines don't work unless I source my .vimrc.

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<Up>" : "\<S-Tab>"
```

If I already have vim open and have sourced my .vimrc and then tried opening any file in the same vim instance then it works without needing to source my .vimrc again.

Comment: What happens if you replace `<Down>`/`<Up>` by `<C-n>`/`<C-p>` ?

Comment: @Zorzi Its the same. I have to source .vimrc for it to work. I'm using supertab now and it works fine but was wondering why would it happen in the first place as opening a file in vim will automatically source the .vimrc.